# JWplayer 7 - how make Video Background Transparent

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using JWplayer 7.4.3 version. I invest much time to make video background transparent but no luck. Can someone please help on this?

```
jwplayer(_videoID).setup({
    file: _vFile,
    image: _vImage,
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    stretching: 'fill', 
    wmode: "transparent", (I tried this)    
    skin: {
        name:"vapor",
        background:"transparent !important" (I tried this)
    }               
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll set this in your CSS file or within `<style></style>` tags in the header, rather than the JS player setup. "Background" actually effects a number of elements (.jw-dock-button, .jw-icon-display-container, .jw-controlbar, .jw-menu, .jw-slider-volume), so you may want to be more specific in what you're calling out. Assuming you want a transparent control bar, you can use

```
.jw-controlbar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  }
```

See "colors" in the [CSS Skinning Reference](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_reference/) and the [DOM Visual Structure Reference](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/css-skinning-reference.html) for more info.